# Call a function at the end of an application in .NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently working on a web application based on ASP.Net. **I need to do some treatments when the application is stopped or is dying**.

In the `HttpApplication` inherited class, I know that I can define some event handler methods, notabily :

- `Application_Error`(object sender, EventArgs e)
- `Application_End`(object sender, EventArgs e)

I wondered if I must put my code on the `Application_End` method AND the `Application_Error` method, or if the `Application_End` is fired even on error.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288350/application-end-global-asax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178473(v%3dvs.100)):

> `Application_Error` can be raised at any phase in the application life cycle.

while

> `Application_End` [is] called once per lifetime of the application before the application is unloaded.

I would use the second one.

note that it'll not be called is the application is dying because of a `StackoverflowException` nor an `OutOfMemoryException`

Answer (score 1):

**It should be sufficient to simply put your code in the `Application_end` method, because this method will be called no matter what if the app is terminated. (including termation by error)**

> `Application_EndRequest` is the only event that is guaranteed to be
>   raised in every request, because a request can be short-circuited. For
>   example, if two modules handle the `Application_BeginRequest` event and
>   the first one throws an exception, the `Application_BeginRequest` event
>   will not be called for the second module. However, the
>   `Application_EndRequest` method is always called to allow the
>   application to clean up resources.

Also your try catch blocks should catch any errors that would end the app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178473(v%3dvs.100)